# .htaccess redirection manually mapping query strings to hashes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I had really a simple site written in PHP that I have just rewritten into a single-page HTML only solution (using `#`-sections).

Now I would like to map the old querystrings used to new hash-based URLs instead. That would mean that for example `?id=itemA` should become `#newAndImprovedItemA` (the old ids are not the same as the new hashes, yet since there are only four possible values, it shouldn't be too much work to manually map them I guess). Apparently this is not working with a simple RedirectPermanent, but from what I understand I have to use RewriteRules. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with that at all, so I wasn't able to come up with anything that is properly working yet.

At the moment I am using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=itemA$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /#newAndImprovedItemA [L]
```

which will redirect me to the new `index.html`, but will not add the hash. Honestly, I do not have too much of a clue what that code is supposed to do, so it might be way off (bear with me in that case), yet I am unfortunately not able to understand what people are writing in other posts regarding that topic.

What would be a simple possibility to just map `index.php?id=itemA` to `#newAndImprovedItemA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes are a purely client-side operation. Your rewrite is only doing an Apache internal-only redirect, without affecting the client at all. You'd have to force a full-blown HTTP 30x redirect, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /#newAndImprovedItemA [L,301]
                                                ^^^^
```

which would round-trip through the client. The downside to this is it'll cost you another HTTP request cycle, and change the address in the user's address bar.

Comment: Actually, I *want* a redirect as I am actually serving new (altered) content, I just want to take care of people (and Google) linking to the old URLs.

Comment: In addition to that I found that I have to use `[L,301,NE]` (ie. non-escape mode) so that the `#` symbol won't turn into a `%23`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it with this htaccess code (a little dirty, but works just perfect):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|xml|json|css|js|php|html|htm)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)($|/)$ /test2/?$1#$1 [R,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)($|/)$ /test2/?$1/$2#$1/$2 [R,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)($|/)$ /test2/?$1/$2/$3#$1/$2/$3 [R,NE,L]
```

"/test2" is just for local wamp test domain pourpose only

Example results:

```
http://localhost/test2/111 --> http://localhost/test2/?111#111
http://localhost/test2/111/ --> http://localhost/test2/?111#111
http://localhost/test2/111/222 --> http://localhost/test2/?111/222#111/222
http://localhost/test2/111/222/ --> http://localhost/test2/?111/222#111/222
```

Hope this helps because it take several hours to me to find a solution for this. When using a # site and want facebook open graph, this is the best solution so far.

Bye